# Null check operator used on a null value Carousel Flutter

Tags: flutter, carousel

Good Morning,
I'm trying to put a Carousel on the home page looking for Firebase data, but for some reason, the first time I load the application it appears the message below:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═════════════════════════════════════ ══════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building DotsIndicator (animation: PageController # 734f9 (one client, offset 0.0), dirty, state: _AnimatedState # 636ca):
Null check operator used on a null value
```

and the screen looks like this:

[image: Screen Fail]

After giving a hot reload the error continues to appear, but the image is loaded successfully, any tips of what I can do?

[image: Screen Ok]

HomeManager:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provantagens_app/models/section.dart';

class HomeManager extends ChangeNotifier{
  HomeManager({this.images}){
    _loadSections();
    images = images ?? [];
  }


  void addSection(Section section){
    _editingSections.add(section);
    notifyListeners();
  }



  final List<dynamic> _sections = [];
  List<String> images;
  List<dynamic> newImages;
  List<dynamic> _editingSections = [];

  bool editing = false;
  bool loading = false;
  int index, totalItems;




  final Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;


  Future<void> _loadSections() async{
    loading = true;
    firestore.collection('home').snapshots().listen((snapshot){
      _sections.clear();
      for(final DocumentSnapshot document in snapshot.documents){
        _sections.add( Section.fromDocument(document));
       images = List<String>.from(document.data['images'] as List<dynamic>);
      }
    });
    loading = false;
    notifyListeners();

  }

  List<dynamic>  get sections {
    if(editing)
      return _editingSections;
    else
      return _sections;
  }

  void enterEditing({Section section}){
    editing = true;

    _editingSections = _sections.map((s) => s.clone()).toList();

    defineIndex(section: section);

    notifyListeners();
  }


  void saveEditing() async{
    bool valid = true;
    for(final section in _editingSections){
      if(!section.valid()) valid = false;
    }
    if(!valid) return;
    loading = true;
    notifyListeners();


    for(final section in _editingSections){
      await section.save();
    }

    for(final section in List.from(_sections)){
      if(!_editingSections.any((s) => s.id == section.id)){
        await section.delete();
      }
    }

    loading = false;
    editing = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void discardEditing(){
    editing = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeSection(Section section){
    _editingSections.remove(section);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void onMoveUp(Section section){
    int index = _editingSections.indexOf(section);

    if(index != 0) {
      _editingSections.remove(section);
      _editingSections.insert(index - 1, section);
      index = _editingSections.indexOf(section);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  HomeManager clone(){
    return HomeManager(
      images: List.from(images),

    );
  }



  void onMoveDown(Section section){

    index = _editingSections.indexOf(section);
    totalItems = _editingSections.length;
    if(index < totalItems - 1){
      _editingSections.remove(section);
      _editingSections.insert(index + 1, section);
      index = _editingSections.indexOf(section);
    }else{
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void defineIndex({Section section}){
    index = _editingSections.indexOf(section);
    totalItems = _editingSections.length;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

HomeScreen:

```
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provantagens_app/commom/custom_drawer.dart';
import 'package:provantagens_app/commom/custom_icons_icons.dart';
import 'package:provantagens_app/models/home_manager.dart';
import 'package:provantagens_app/models/section.dart';
import 'package:provantagens_app/screens/home/components/home_carousel.dart';
import 'package:provantagens_app/screens/home/components/menu_icon_tile.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';


// ignore: must_be_immutable
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  HomeManager homeManager;
  Section section;
  List<Widget> get children => null;
  String videoUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFnDo3JUzjs';
  int index;
  var _tapPosition;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: const [
            Colors.white,
            Colors.white,
          ], begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter)),
      child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          drawer: CustomDrawer(),
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
            title: Text('Página inicial', style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 158, 8))),
            centerTitle: true,
            actions: <Widget>[
              Divider(),
            ],
          ),
          body: Consumer<HomeManager>(
            builder: (_, homeManager, __){
              return ListView(children: <Widget>[
                AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1,
                  child:HomeCarousel(homeManager),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:12.0),
                          child: MenuIconTile(title: 'Parceiros', iconData: Icons.apartment, page: 1,),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:7.0),
                          child: MenuIconTile(title: 'Beneficios', iconData: Icons.card_giftcard, page: 2,),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right:3.0),
                          child: MenuIconTile(title: 'Suporte', iconData: Icons.help_outline, page: 6,),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        MenuIconTile(iconData: Icons.assignment,
                            title: 'Dados pessoais',
                            page: 3)
                        ,
                        MenuIconTile(iconData: Icons.credit_card_outlined,
                            title: 'Meu cartão',
                            page: 4)
                        ,
                        MenuIconTile(iconData: Icons.account_balance_wallet_outlined,
                          title: 'Pagamento',
                          page: 5,)
                        ,
                      ],
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                    Consumer<HomeManager>(
                      builder: (_, sec, __){
                        return RaisedButton(
                          child: Text('Teste'),
                          onPressed: (){
                            Navigator.of(context)
                                .pushReplacementNamed('/teste',
                                arguments: sec);
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    Text('Saiba onde usar o seu', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),),
                    Text('Cartão Pró Vantagens', style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 158, 8), fontSize: 30),),
                    AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 1,
                      child: Image.network(
                        'https://static.wixstatic.com/media/d170e1_80b5f6510f5841c19046f1ed5bca71e4~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_745,h_595,al_c,q_90,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/Arte_Cart%C3%83%C2%B5es.webp',
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    Container(
                      height: 150,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: 1,
                            child: Image.network(
                              'https://static.wixstatic.com/media/d170e1_486dd638987b4ef48d12a4bafee20e80~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_684,h_547,al_c,q_90,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/Arte_Cart%C3%83%C2%B5es_2.webp',
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0),
                            child: RichText(
                              text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: 'Adquira já o seu',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: '\n\CARTÃO PRÓ VANTAGENS',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 158, 8)),
                                ),
                              ]),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    tableBeneficios(),
                    Divider(),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                              'O cartão Pró-Vantagens é sediado na cidade de Hortolândia/SP e já está no mercado há mais de 3 anos. Somos um time de profissionais apaixonados por gestão de benefícios e empenhados em gerar o máximo de valor para os conveniados.'),
                          FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                launch(
                                    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFnDo3JUzjs');
                              },
                              child: Text('SAIBA MAIS')),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 105, 190, 90),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                                child: Text(
                                  '©  2020 todos os direitos reservados a Cartão Pró Vantagens.',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Divider(),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Rua Luís Camilo de Camargo, 175 -\n\Centro, Hortolândia (piso superior)',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(CustomIcons.facebook),
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    launch(
                                        'https://www.facebook.com/provantagens/');
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(CustomIcons.instagram),
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    launch(
                                        'https://www.instagram.com/cartaoprovantagens/');
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ]);
            },
          )
          ),

    );
  }

  tableBeneficios() {
    return Table(
      defaultColumnWidth: FlexColumnWidth(120.0),
      border: TableBorder(
        horizontalInside: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.black,
          style: BorderStyle.solid,
          width: 1.0,
        ),
        verticalInside: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.black,
          style: BorderStyle.solid,
          width: 1.0,
        ),
      ),
      children: [
        _criarTituloTable(",Plus, Premium"),
        _criarLinhaTable("Seguro de vida\n\(Morte Acidental),X,X"),
        _criarLinhaTable("Seguro de Vida\n\(Qualquer natureza),,X"),
        _criarLinhaTable("Invalidez Total e Parcial,X,X"),
        _criarLinhaTable("Assistência Residencial,X,X"),
        _criarLinhaTable("Assistência Funeral,X,X"),
        _criarLinhaTable("Assistência Pet,X,X"),
        _criarLinhaTable("Assistência Natalidade,X,X"),
        _criarLinhaTable("Assistência Eletroassist,X,X"),
        _criarLinhaTable("Assistência Alimentação,X,X"),
        _criarLinhaTable("Descontos em Parceiros,X,X"),
      ],
    );
  }

  _criarLinhaTable(String listaNomes) {
    return TableRow(
      children: listaNomes.split(',').map((name) {
        return Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(
                text: name != "X" ? '' : 'X',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: name != 'X' ? name : '',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 158, 8)),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }

  _criarTituloTable(String listaNomes) {
    return TableRow(
      children: listaNomes.split(',').map((name) {
        return Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(
                text: name == "" ? '' : 'Plano ',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: name,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 30, 158, 8)),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
  void _storePosition(TapDownDetails details) {
    _tapPosition = details.globalPosition;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I forked the library to create a custom carousel for my company's project, and since we updated flutter to 2.x we had the same problem.

To fix this just update boolean expressions like

```
if(carouselState.pageController.position.minScrollExtent == null ||
carouselState.pageController.position.maxScrollExtent == null){ ... }
```

to

```
if(!carouselState.pageController.position.hasContentDimensions){ ... }
```

[Here is flutter's github reference.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66250)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

So I edited scrollposition.dart package

from line 133

```
@override    
//double get minScrollExtent => _minScrollExtent!;    
// double? _minScrollExtent;    
double get minScrollExtent {    
if (_minScrollExtent == null) {    
    _minScrollExtent = 0.0;    
    }    
return double.parse(_minScrollExtent.toString());    
}    
double? _minScrollExtent;    
@override    
// double get maxScrollExtent => _maxScrollExtent!;    
// double? _maxScrollExtent;    
double get maxScrollExtent {    
if (_maxScrollExtent == null) {    
     _maxScrollExtent = 0.0;    
    }    
return double.parse(_maxScrollExtent.toString());    
}    
double? _maxScrollExtent;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just upgrade to `^3.0.0` Check here https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.
This is how I solved it

```
class PlansPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlansPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PlansPage> createState() => _PlansPageState();
}

class _PlansPageState extends State<PlansPage> {
    int _currentPage = 1;

    late CarouselController carouselController;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        carouselController = CarouselController();
     }
}
```

Then put initialization the carouselController inside the initState method I was able to use the methods jumpToPage(_currentPage ) and animateToPage(_currentPage) etc.

I use animateToPage inside GestureDetector in onTap.

```
onTap: () {
    setState(() {
        _currentPage = pageIndex;
     });

    carouselController.animateToPage(_currentPage);
},
```

I apologize in advance if this is inappropriate.

Comment: You are the man omg I could not figure it. I was reading github issues for hours I thought I was the only one with this issue!!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the similar problem as follows. You can take advantage of the Boolean variable. I hope, help you.

```
child: !loading ? HomeCarousel(homeManager) : Center(child:ProgressIndicator()),
```

or

```
child: isLoading ? HomeCarousel(homeManager) : SplashScreen(),
```

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Loading...')
      ),
  


    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using GetX for state management. So I shifted the initialization of CarouselController from the same page to the getX controller (can be done with any controller, not necessarily getX). This way, it was initialized with the dependency of the controller and the error was gone.

Hope it helps someone :)