# I tried using carousel_slider in my flutter project, it works but I get this warning in my debug console. What can I do to eradicate this?

Tags: flutter, dart

The error is coming from the package

[The error is coming from line 135](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yYN2.png)

This is the warning I get from my debug console
This happens as the carousel slides

```
E/flutter (13716): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null 
check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (13716): #0      CarouselSliderState.getTimer.<anonymous closure>
package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart:135
E/flutter (13716): #1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
E/flutter (13716): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter (13716): #3      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
E/flutter (13716): #4      _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> 
(dart:async/zone.dart:1281:26)
E/flutter (13716): #5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1444:13)
E/flutter (13716): #6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter (13716): #7      _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> 
(dart:async/zone.dart:1265:26)
E/flutter (13716): #8      _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:395:19)
E/flutter (13716): #9      _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:426:5)
E/flutter (13716): #10     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate- 
patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
E/flutter (13716):
```

Comment: [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72747489/10910438)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is hard to answer in its current state. Can you provide the code snippet where the error occurs?

Comment: @JoRa I've added a screenshot of where the error is coming from

Answer (score 1):

According to the error and the screenshot, either `carouselState`, `pageController` or `page` is null, and you are using `null check operator (!)` to say that these variables can not be null. You can check these variables if they are null or not. Or you can use `nullable operator (?)` instead of `null check operator (!)`.